# Is there any ASP.NET MVC software that has similar functionalities to ScrewTurn?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, screwturn

I downloaded **ScrewTurn** and liked the all functionalities it presents (pages revisions, rollback, drafts, ...). But, ScrewTurn is written in **Web Form**. I'd like to know how I can find something similar in **ASP.NET MVC** side.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why would you explicitly want ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Because is the only framework I know.

Comment: Because is the only framework I know. I case I need to customize it, I need to know where to start. I just look at the .aspx pages and I'm completly lost.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try RoadKill : http://roadkill.codeplex.com/

> Roadkill .NET is a lightweight but powerful Wiki engine built on the
>   following foundations: .NET 4.0
>
> jQuery
>
> ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor
>
> NHibernate
>
> Creole, Media Wiki and Markdown syntax support
>
> Bootstrap-based UI.
>
> SQL Server (although it supports mySQL, SQlite, Postgres - anything
>   that NHibernate  supports)
>
> It's themeable, well documented, supports Active Directory
>   authentication and is (I hope) extremely easy to use. It's Free Open
>   Source (FOSS)

Comment: Brad : well it seems easy to use, however i haven't been able to make it work on my website, it keeps making exception errors.
but should try it anyway, maybe i don't have all the elements installed..

Answer (score 0):

The library that comes to mind for something similar is [PlexWiki](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/).

It is able to store everything in the DB to allow history, drafts, rollbacks, etc.  Took me at most an hour to get most of this functionality integrated into my MVC site.